# 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command I'm using windows 10. what should I do?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I've recently installed laravel and have written some tests in /tests directory but when I use phpunit at cmd in the same folder that phpunit.xml exists, it says 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command I'm using windows 10. what should I do?

Comment: What command are you trying to use?

Comment: vendor\bin\phpunit

Comment: you must run phpunit that are in the `vendor` directory, or try to install phpunit globally [Installing PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html)

Answer (score 52):

This is linux based code..

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Try this for windows..

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. I'm also on Windows.

Comment: This is great. It fixed it.

Answer (score 10):

Please try this command for windows:

`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install dependencies via composer

   `$ composer update`
2. Run tests

   `$ vendor/bin/phpunit`